How do I find average sales per week for a retail outlet category when there are multiple outlet data and categories every week in PowerBI?
In this example, I have output per week for clothing and footwear outlets (I have a a large database with multiple outlets and data spanning over 50,000 lines). In week 1 and week 2, I have only sales from Clothing-1 Outlet. I open a new clothing outlet in week 3. In week 4, I open my first footwear outlet. In week 6, my 3rd clothing outlet opens and in week 7 my 2nd footwear outlet opens. Due to financial reasons, I had to shut my 2nd clothing outlet in week 8.



Week
Outlet
Sales




1
Clothing-1
9


1
Clothing-1
5


2
Clothing-1
4


2
Clothing-1
5


2
Clothing-1
6


3
Clothing-1
10


3
Clothing-1
6


3
Clothing-2
4


3
Clothing-2
7


3
Clothing-2
6


4
Clothing-1
2


4
Clothing-2
10


4
Clothing-2
14


4
Footwear-1
1


4
Footwear-1
3


4
Footwear-1
2


4
Footwear-1
3


5
Clothing-1
5


5
Clothing-1
3


5
Clothing-1
2


5
Clothing-2
3


5
Clothing-2
6


5
Clothing-2
7


5
Clothing-2
7


5
Clothing-2
9


5
Footwear-1
2


5
Footwear-1
11


6
Clothing-1
4


6
Clothing-2
8


6
Clothing-3
8


6
Clothing-3
5


6
Footwear-1
3


7
Clothing-1
10


7
Clothing-1
4


7
Clothing-2
6


7
Clothing-2
8


7
Clothing-3
6


7
Footwear-1
9


7
Footwear-2
6


7
Footwear-2
5


7
Footwear-2
4


8
Clothing-1
9


8
Clothing-3
5


8
Clothing-3
5


8
Footwear-1
4


8
Footwear-1
4


8
Footwear-2
9


9
Clothing-1
9


9
Clothing-3
5


9
Footwear-1
4


9
Footwear-2
9



I need to find the effective and total sales week on week per clothing and footwear outlets. For eg, in week 6, I have a total of 25 sales in clothing over three outlets. My effective sales that week in clothing is hence 25/3 = 8.33 per outlet. In week 8, my second clothing outlet closes, so my effective sales in clothing that week is 19/2 = 9.5 per outlet. In the same week, my effective sales in footwear is 17/2 = 8.5.
I was hoping to find a DAX code in powerBI that might help with the analysis.
I tried analysing the data in excel but it takes forever to compute each category. In some cases, I have almost 14 outlets which open and close in different weeks so I really can't figure out how to proceed.
Additional Question:
Now, if in week 4, clothing-1 had no sales but were open, I wouldn't have a row for clothing-1 in week 4. I know the store isn't shut down because they have sales in the ensuing weeks. If I recalculate based on this logic, I should have a clothing total sales of 24 in week 4 and my average sales would be 12 despite only clothing-2 making sales. Can this somehow be incorporated too?

The first thing I think you need is a count of active outlets.
=DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[Outlet])
So you end up with something like this:
Active Outlet Count 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 4 4 5

I believe your examples are incorrect.  Week6:25/3=>8.333 not 6.333.  Week8: Footwear total => 17 not 13

Added an additional, more complicated question at the end.

WRT your second question, you can certainly locate a pattern of sales-no sales-sales and adjust it, but that is not sufficient to determine whether a store is closed vs open with no sales. If a store has no sales at the beginning or end of your time frame, there is no method to differentiate no sales from not open. Also, if a store is temporarily closed in the middle, your method will not differentiate. You should speak with whoever is providing you this data base to include sufficient information to be able to differentiate. The simplest would be to include a line were Sale=0.

I'm more familiar with Power Query M code where is pretty simple:
In the Advanced Editor:
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ldPBCsIwEATQf8m5gt2kbfYs+BOlhx5EBbEgBX9fbCAhmUnRYx/DZjtNx9G0pjGnx7Le7s/r4fugZmoIdxtLyY5zJd1vbEtuj9xJXOKZwAPnMMSVswVZ0iroLvp5Wdb3ZX6F1TlbzrKX7niJwJW0IAtPp1aAh79YI5O3BG5DVz2/Qn053CPbOneRSbND5cKBO+RUFrBHtlk6W0WRhaclvg9wWNDzf9bzUnY4W9D9zOnbK99E+ZHKZyuZPX0A", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Week = _t, Outlet = _t, Sales = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Week", Int64.Type}, {"Outlet", type text}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}}),
    
//add columnm to determine Footwear vs Clothing type
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Type", each Text.Split([Outlet],"-"){0}, type text),

//Group by Type and Week
//Then compute total and average per unique store
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Week", "Type"}, {
        {"Total Sales", each List.Sum([Sales]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Sales per Outlet", each List.Sum([Sales]) / List.Count(List.Distinct([Outlet])), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"


To do this all in DAX, you may try:

Add a column to your original Table (named SalesTable

    Type = LEFT([Outlet],FIND("-",[Outlet])-1)

Then, create a new table:
SummaryTable = SUMMARIZE('SalesTable'  
      ,[Week] 
      , [Type]
      , "Total Sales", SUM('SalesTable'[Sales])
      , "Average Sales", SUM('SalesTable'[Sales]) / DISTINCTCOUNT('SalesTable'[Outlet])
      )  


Edit:Add zero sales entries if there is a gap for a particular store
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ldNBCsIwEAXQu2RdwUzSNrMWvETpwoWoIBak4PXFRhKa/1N02cdnZjJJh8FY05jDfZqvt8dl9/lQMzaE24WlZM+5ku4WdiXbPXcSl9QTuOcci/iSvz3RffLjNM2v8+kZZ+TsOMtWuuXbAq6kBVl4Oh8fuP+LNTE5JbCNu+r4W+nK4gHZ1blNTDbbV14WuEfOywIOyG6VXo2iyMLTks4DHAcM/OcMfCkbvBrQ/8z57pVPoryl8trKa1tymeMb", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Week = _t, Outlet = _t, Sales = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Week", Int64.Type}, {"Outlet", type text}, {"Sales", type number}}),
   
//Find missing weeks and create a zero(0) sales record for those weeks
    #"Grouped Outlet" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Outlet"}, {
        {"Missing Weeks", (t)=>
            let 
                #"Missing" = List.RemoveMatchingItems({List.Min(t[Week])..List.Max(t[Week])}, t[Week]),
                #"Records"= List.Accumulate(
                    #"Missing",
                    {},
                    (s,c)=> s & {[Outlet=t[Outlet]{0}, Week=c, Sales=0]}
                )
            in Table.FromRecords(#"Records"), type table[Outlet=text, Week=Int64.Type, Sales=number]}}),
    #"Expanded Missing Weeks" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Outlet", "Missing Weeks", {"Week", "Sales"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Missing Weeks", each ([Week] <> null)),

//Combine missing weeks with original table
    #"Combine" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", #"Filtered Rows"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Combine, each true),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Week", Order.Ascending}, {"Outlet", Order.Ascending}}),

//add columnm to determine Footwear vs Clothing type
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Type", each Text.Split([Outlet],"-"){0}, type text),

//Group by Type and Week
//Then compute total and average per unique store
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Week", "Type"}, {
        {"Total Sales", each List.Sum([Sales]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Sales per Outlet", each List.Sum([Sales]) / List.Count(List.Distinct([Outlet])), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"


Thanks a lot Ron. Yeah, the examples were wrong, I've modified them. Now, if in week 4, clothing-1 had no sales but were open, I wouldn't have a row for clothing-1 in week 4. I know the store isn't shut down because they have sales in the ensuing weeks. If I recalculate based on this logic, I should have a clothing total sales of 24 in week 4 and my average sales would be 12 despite only clothing-2 making sales. Can this somehow be incorporated too?

@NoviceatPBI You would have to provide additional information. For example, how could you differentiate between a store with no sales in weeks 8 and 9 (the last two weeks) vs a store that closed in week 8? How would you differentiate a store that was temporarily closed from one that had no sales? It would be best to have your data entered so that a store that was open but with no sales showed a sales of zero (0) in your data.

Let us assume there are no stores which temporarily close. Either they close forever or they are open but have no sales.  One way to differentiate a store with no sales vs a store that closed forever would that it in the ensuing weeks, the open store would have some sales happening. Like when Clothing-2 closed forever in week 8, it did not reappear afterwards. But  if in week 4, clothing-1 had no sales but were open, then it would continue having sales in week 5-8..

@NoviceatPBI It does not seem like a robust method. What if Clothing-2 had sales in Week 10. Then your numbers would be off for week 9 since there would be no method of telling if it were open during that last week.

I understand that there's a fallacy there but that's totally fine. In excel, I tried to sort the data based on week no. and then looked for unique number of clothing stores from the said week. If there is a change, then I know one of the stores have closed down indefinitely.

@NoviceatPBI See last Edit for adding zero sales records when there is a gap in the week numbers for a particular store.  This should do what you describe.

Thank you Ron for your amazing tips. :-). Will do accordingly.
